# Log users ip upon login and submit to database with username

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that has a login to it but a person has to pay to access the website and as my customer base grows I would like to add a function that will log a persons IP address upon login and submit it to a database along with their username. We have roughly 50 users at the moment so we don't want it overloaded with db entries.

Is there efficient and effective way to do this?

Or another way to make sure people aren't sharing accounts? We can't really whitelist IP's due to dynamic IP's

Thanks

Comment: Verified accounts using email addresses is one method having that column as UNIQUE, but then again, people have more than one email address nowadays, so that's next to impossible to stop anyone from having ghost accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Get the client's ipaddress:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

But you could also connect a user to an email-address so that a user will have trouble making multiple accounts.
It is not safe to rely on IP-addresses alone

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to use the normal apache/nginx log file and analyze it using tools like [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/). The logs contain a lot of data, but they are not too big for current computers. With good tools you gather far more information about your users than you will ever get by just storing the user's IP in your database, for example you can see if they found your web page using a search engine and which browser they are using.

If you still think your log files are too big you can also use logrotate to periodically start a new file and compress the old one. gz compression rate of such files is above 90%!

A completely different way is to use an external service like [Google Analytics](https://www.google.ch/analytics/)